# error: ‘class std::vector<Shape*>’ has no member named ‘sort’

Tags: c++, vector

I have a code where I am drawing different Shape , now there can be preference on which one to draw first among say Square, rectangle and triangle . I have override the "<" ( less than operator for base class Shape. My preference of drawing is in increasing order as mentioned in typeOrderTable. Therefore triangle will be drawn before Square But upon compilation I get the error error: ‘class std::vector’ has no member named ‘sort’.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


class Shape 
{ 
    public: 
    virtual void Draw() const = 0; 
    virtual bool Precedes(const Shape&) const ;
    bool operator<(const Shape& s) 
    {
        return Precedes(s);
    }
    private:    
    static char* typeOrderTable[];
};

char* Shape::typeOrderTable[] = {"Rectangle","Square","Triangle",0 };

bool Shape::Precedes(const Shape& s) const 
{
    const char* thisType = typeid(*this).name();    
    const char* argType = typeid(s).name();    
    bool done = false;    int thisOrd = -1;    
    int argOrd = -1;    
    for (int i=0; !done; i++)    
    {        
        const char* tableEntry = typeOrderTable[i];
        if (tableEntry != 0)        
        {            
            if (strcmp(tableEntry, thisType) == 0)                
            thisOrd = i;            
            if (strcmp(tableEntry, argType) == 0)                
            argOrd = i;
            if ((argOrd > 0) && (thisOrd > 0))                
            done = true;        

        }        
        else // table entry == 0            
        done = true;    
    }    
    return thisOrd < argOrd; 
}

class Square : public Shape 
{ 
    public: 
    virtual void Draw() const 
    { 
        std::cout << "Inside Draw of Square \n" ; 

    } 
};

class Rectangle : public Shape 
{ 
    public: 
    virtual void Draw() const 
    { 
        std::cout << "Inside Draw of Rectangle \n" ; 

    } 
};

class Triangle : public Shape 
{ 
    public: 
    virtual void Draw() const 
    { 
        std::cout << "Inside Draw of Triangle \n" ; 

    } 
};

void DrawAllShapes(std::vector<Shape*>& list) 
{        
    std::vector<Shape*> orderedList = list;
    orderedList.sort();    
    std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it =orderedList.begin();
    for (;it!=orderedList.end(); ++it)
    (*it)->Draw(); 
}

int main() 
{
std::vector<Shape*> vec;
vec.push_back(new Triangle);
vec.push_back(new Square);
vec.push_back(new Rectangle);
vec.push_back(new Square);
DrawAllShapes(vec);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Search for sort, and you'll see only lists have it as a member, to make it more efficient and remove requirements: http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=sort&button=

Comment: This is hardly a [mcve]. You should know better at your rep.

Comment: `typeid(*this).name()` -- This is an implementation-defined name.  There is no guarantee the name will be "Rectangle", "Triangle", etc. as you believe they would be.  Thus the `operator <` is more than likely flawed to begin with.

Comment: I compiled this code online with proposed solution by removing the third parameter as I am overloading the < ( less than operator ) and it works for me and I get the desired output .

Comment: @Invictus The point is that you should not use `name()` and assume it will be a name you think it will be.  You came up with names that, by chance, match with that compiler's interpretation, given the compiler options.  Change compiler options or even compilers, and the output / results may turn out differently.  Come with with your own naming scheme -- don't rely on the compiler's internal naming mechanism.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got the point . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [`std::vector<...>::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Instead, you will need to use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

```
std::sort(orderedList.begin(), orderedList.end());
```

**However**, this will try to compare the *pointers* in your `std::vector<Shape*>` (hint: refactor this if at all possible). Instead, you will need to pass a custom comparator that dereferences the pointers:

```
std::sort(
    orderedList.begin(),
    orderedList.end(),
    [](Shape *a, Shape *b) { return *a < *b; }
);
```

Comment: I compiled this code online with proposed solution by removing the third parameter as I am overloading the < ( less than operator ) and it works for me and I get the desired output